# NOW() formula not working as expected

Tags: formula, datetime

I have a process builder that contains the NOW() formula for whenever a particular action is completed. I am running into the issue of it populating the date/time as the day before at 6:00pm. Would anyone happen to know what might be going on?

---

Whenever a value is selected in the Request Extension picklist field it is supposed to populate the current date/time in the Extension Requested Date field. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need details (about the PB, and about the field being updated). but I suspect timezone shenanigans

Comment: In the future, please add details via **[edit]** to the original question, rather than posting an "answer".

Comment: Use TEXT(NOW()) also see this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty  I am getting “The formula expression is invalid: Formula result type is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Date)”

Comment: Your field name is date while you are trying to catch time. Is your field named as date but actually a date time type or is it just date? Can you confirm your field type.

Comment: @Raj it is a date/time field